Snakemake: mtime rerun trigger forces rerunning previous completed steps when using temporary communal data
My workflow branches like so:
A -> temp(B) -> C ...
A -> temp(B) -> D
So when I want to produce D after C, it regenerates B, but by doing so, my workflow then thinks C needs to be rerun because it was created before B. Is the only way around this just to do
A -> temp(B_C) -> C ...
A -> temp(B_D) -> D
Or is there another way?
The above solution does work but I would prefer a solution that does not require me to dig through all my rules.

How about
rule ONE:
    input:
        A 
    output:
        temp(B)
    shell:
        test.sh
        
rule TWO:
    input:
        B 
    output:
        C
    shell:
        test2.sh
        
rule THREE:
    input:
        B
    ouput:
        D
    shell:
        test3.sh

This should create B once, but deletes it after C and D are done.
